# ViewFactory with PyQt5

Tags: javafx, model-view-controller, pyqt

I am a beginner in coding and learning by experiment. I already have done this pattern using java in a tutorial and I was trying to replicate the pattern in python.

In JavaFX it is possible to do as follows,

1. initiate controller (calling controls with @FXML)
2. load FXML file

In PyQt the controller doesn't know anything about the controls as there is no similar annotation as @PyQt for example so I replaced that by passing the loaded window to the controller

1. initiate controller
2. load .ui file (gives `UIloader` not a loader object but the window object)
3. passing the loaded window to the controller and at that point apply binding `controller.setWindow(self.UIloader)`

the code as shown,

```
class ViewFactory:

__emailManager: EmailManager

def __init__(self, emailManager):
    self.__emailManager = emailManager

def __initializeStage(self, baseController: BaseController):
    try:
        self.UIloader = uic.loadUi(relpath(baseController.getUIName()), None)
    except IOError as e:
        raise(e)
        return

    self.UIloader.show()

def showLoginWindow(self):
    print("show login window")
    controller = LoginWindowController(self.__emailManager, self, "loginWindow.ui")
    self.__initializeStage(controller)
    controller.setWindow(self.UIloader)


def showMainWindow(self):
    print("show Main window")
    controller = MainWindowController(self.__emailManager, self, "mainWindow.ui")
    self.__initializeStage(controller)

class LoginWindowController(BaseController):

UIloader = None
def __init__(self, emailManager, viewFactory, uiName ):
    BaseController.__init__(self, emailManager, viewFactory, uiName)
    self.viewFactory = viewFactory

def setWindow(self, UIloader):
    self.UIloader = UIloader
    self.UIloader.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_login_btn_clicked)

def on_login_btn_clicked(self):
    print("clicked")
```

[github](https://github.com/mourKa86/mvcPthon)

My question is that this solution of passing the window to the controller works only when I add a break point in the function setWindow() but it doesn't work in a normal run.

one more thing is that when I initiate a second window at pressing the button, the first window closes in the python code not as in java where both windows would be shown.

What is happening there?

Comment: What do you mean by "passing the window back"? Also, different languages follow different concepts and aspects; there's nothing that is "passed back" in your code, there's just a single `return` statement that just results in a `None`. Besides, your structure is quite convoluted (at least, in python terms); trying to replicate a behavior doesn't mean that you could (nor should) replicate the semantics. What are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: All the available tutorials online for applying mvc for __python__ is minimal with short examples. I did the tutorial in Java using JavaFX building a full software with threads, services, handling multiple windows and so on. As I didn't find anything for python online even paid, I am trying to take it step by step by applying the same concepts in python. `controller.setWindow(self.UIloader)` >> passing the window to the controller. If you applied any breakpoint in `setWindow` function, actually makes the binding works. With no breakpoint, the binding doesn't take place.

Comment: What's the purpose of using a java-based mvc example? It seems totally unsuited to the application you're trying to write, and overcomplicates what should be simple task whilst adding no useful functionality. Your current code could easily be reduced to a single module of 40-50 lines. That should be enough to show the login window, verify the email/password, and then show the main window (or error messages as appropriate). If you're a beginner, try to concentrate on writing a functioning program rather than getting bogged down in design principles and such-like. Practicality beats Purity.

Comment: @Mour_Ka it doesn't work because the `controller` object gets out of scope and is garbage collected, and being `on_login_btn_clicked` part of `controller`, it gets destroyed as well and is disconnected from the signal. Don't try to create complex designs when they are not practical: the MVC pattern makes sense when the separation between its components is really important (ie. for maintenance and implementation), in reality most small-medium sized programs don't need that at all, it doesn't provide any real benefit, it usually just creates pitfalls like yours, caused by unnecessary complexity.